# Live or hourly data sync from Firebase to BigQuery

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

We are using firebase to capture events on our App.

We have connected it with BigQuery so that the analytics data captured by firebase is exported to BigQuery.

The only problem for us is that the data export to BigQuery happens once in 24hrs. We would like to have the data export to BigQuery every hour.

I have not found a way to do this on Firebase console.

I was wondering if there is any way to ensure hourly export to BigQuery from Firebase analytics.

Comment: What do you mean it happens only every 24 hours? It's realtime, AFAIK https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/real-time-exporting-of-analytics-data-into-bigquery.html

Answer (score 2):

`events_` table is what is updated every 24 hours.

If you want to get near real-time data, use the `events_intratable_` table

For further reading: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/real-time-exporting-of-analytics-data-into-bigquery.html